# WooCommerce instantly update js code without it being cached

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, woocommerce

In **plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.min.js**

When I edit this file and save it, and when I visit the website, the old code it still being served.

When I add this line ( define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true); ) in wp-config.php changes are immediately there when code (js) is updated , but generally this is not safe approach.

Is there another way I could get immediate change of updated js code?

Comment: You should never edit WooCommerce core files for many reasons. Instead, you can dequeue frontend/checkout.min.js script and enqueue/register your own modified script.

Comment: You may need to make some changes to WC_Frontend_Scripts Class via the available hooks regarding checkout.